# Add HTML to <h:messages />

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

The alert HTML code is:

```
<div class="alert alert-block">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
  Best check yo self, you're not...
</div>
```

I'm using `<h:messages />` to show my form error, info and warning messages like this:

```
<h:messages errorClass="alert alert-error" infoClass="alert alert-info" warnClass="alert alert-warning"/>
```

The colors and rounded corners are OK but I need to add the close link:

```
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
```

How do I do that with `<h:messages/>`?

**Edit**

If a better understanding is required, here is the twitter bootstrap link to the alert style:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the usual way you add messages ...

```
FacesContext context = 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(your message goes here...
```

the messages should be added from server side... e.g `String myMessage = "here is the text / HTML code..."`

Take a look at this article by BalusC

[Using HTML in JSF messages](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-html-in-jsf-messages.html)

Comment: Ok...I'm gonna start doing this way, I do that on my `html` files like: `<h:inputText requiredMessage="O campo Pesquisa é obrigatório" id="pesquisa" styleClass="input-xxlarge search-query" required="true"/>` and add a `<h:messages />` on the top of my `form`, thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this solution , but it seems like the one... You Are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Just use omnifaces o:messages. The problem will be solved.

e.g `<o:messages escape="false"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert" jsf:rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('InputPassword')}">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <strong>Error </strong>  <h:message for="InputPassword" /> 
                                    </div>
```

Its for JSF 2.2, but you can adapt to previous versions of JSF..